# CodeIgniter giving a 404 not found on public server only

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**Description**

I have a site "searchnwork.com". It uses CodeIgniter. Every page **except** the home page loads fine.

If you go to searchnwork.com, it shows the CI 404 error page.

If you go to searchnwork.com/index.php/users, it shows the UserSignUpController page, which is good.

If I set the `$route['404_override'] = 'UserSignUpController'`, I still get a 404.

Everything works fine on my local server.

---

**Question**

Why am I getting a 404 for searchnwork.com despite the override?

Why am I getting a 404 for searchnwork.com in the first place instead of my default controller?

---

**Code**

```
$route['users'] = "UserSignUpController"; // This loads fine.
$route['default_controller'] = "UserSignUpController"; // This gives a 404...
$route['404_override'] = 'UserSignUpController'; // This doesn't redirect...
```

Comment: Please post your `.htaccess` file content.

Comment: @DonnyP if you cannot find it in your root folder chances are it's not there ;)

Comment: Yea just grepped for it, and it looks like I don't have any .htaccess... there are a bunch of .htaccess on the `bitnami` installation I'm using but all of them say `Deny from all`, and that's it

Comment: `.htaccess` files containing `Deny from all` are to prevent from direct accessing to files inside, and it is okay. You should create a `.htaccess` next to your `index.php` to rewrite URLs.

Comment: I suspect it's a casing issue, your local machine might be windows & the online website might be Linux... As I see you're using mixed words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case sensitive file names.

On MAMP it doesn't seem to care about capitalization. When I uploaded to an actual linux server, CapitalizedFileNames started to fail, since it only searchs for lowercasefilenames. I guess you should use underscores.

Weird that it only fails for index.php.

Comment: The same for WAMP and Ubuntu Server. Saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a `.htaccess` on the server root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also make sure your `/application/config/config.php` is set up properly (these can by left blank and should still work properly)

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: But why would all of my other pages load fine?

Comment: Are you sure you've added it in the right place? I can go to http://searchnwork.com/images/ and see your directory. If it was installed properly, I would not be able to see that directory.

Comment: Thanks justin :) let me try again

Comment: Hmm, just put that next to my `index.php` that gets accessed and restarted Apache. Looks like you can still see `/images` though.

Comment: Maybe it's because this is a `bitnami` instance? Their doc says they do something different for .htaccess... http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache/htaccess_configuration

Comment: I don't think that would cause an issue. I updated my answer with another thing you could try.